# How to extract date in which the hour of the peak value occurred?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I have Hourly time series starts by year 2013 and ends by year 2020 as below and I want to plot only day in which the system load reached it peak:

```
date_time             system_load
2013-01-01 00:00:00    1.0 
2013-01-01 01:00:00    0.9
2013-01-01 02:00:00    0.5
...
2020-12-31 21:00:00    2.1 
2020-12-31 22:00:00    1.8
2020-12-31 23:00:00    0.8
```

The intended dataframe has 'one day(24hours) per year' :

```
date_time             system_load
2013-07-09 00:00:00    3.1
2013-07-09 02:00:00    3.0     
2013-07-09 03:00:00    4.8
2013-07-09 04:00:00    2.6
    ...
2013-07-09 21:00:00    3.7
2013-07-09 22:00:00    3.9
2013-07-09 23:00:00    5.1
2014-09-09 00:00:00    4.1
2014-09-09 02:00:00    5.3
2014-09-09 03:00:00    6.0
2014-09-09 04:00:00    4.8
    ...
2014-09-09 21:00:00    3.5
2014-09-09 22:00:00    2.6
2014-09-09 23:00:00    1.6
  ...
  ...
2020-06-01 00:00:00    4.2
2020-06-01 02:00:00    3.6
2020-06-01 03:00:00    3.9
2020-06-01 04:00:00    2.8
    ...
2020-06-01 21:00:00    2.7
2020-06-01 22:00:00    4.8
2020-06-01 23:00:00    3.8
```

Comment: So, do I understand your problem is: Given a dataframe containing a year's worth of hourly system load readings, you want to create a second data frame containing the 24 hourly readings for the day in which the total load is at it's peak?

Comment: Yes Mr itprorh66 and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get only date and year part from `date_time` column
2. Groupby `year` column and get the row containing the max value of `system_load` column in each group
3. Getting all the time from the original dataframe where the date is the same with the date whose `system_load` value is the max
4. Plot the bar

```py
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])    # Ensure the `date_time` column is datetime type

df['just_date'] = df['date_time'].dt.date
df['year'] = df['date_time'].dt.year

idx = df.groupby(['year'])['system_load'].transform(max) == df['system_load']

df[df['just_date'].isin(df[idx]['just_date'])].plot.bar(x='date_time', y='system_load', rot=45)
```

If in one year there are several days have the same max `system_load` value, the above code returns all. If you want to keep only the first day, you can use [pandas.DataFrame.idxmax()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```py
idx = df.groupby(['year'])['system_load'].idxmax()

df[df['just_date'].isin(df.loc[idx]['just_date'])].plot.bar(x='date_time', y='system_load', rot=45)
```

Comment: Thanks "Ynjxsjmh" for your response. the code gives the days of each month yearly in which the system load is at its peak (i.e  it gives 365 rows per year) but what I want is to get 24 hours reading of the day in which the system load is at its peak(i.e 24 hours"[rows]" per year).

Comment: hanks "Ynjxsjmh" for your response again. The code provides what I want but there is a problem in plotting. The problem is that bars is very thin and the x-axis labels is very very close which results in horizontal black thick bar.By the way if the line plot solve the problem, could please post its code.

Comment: @saadawad I don't think line plot is a good alternative, because the datetime in x axis is not continuous. The hard part in your question is to retrieve the desired date_time, I have already done it for you, you can plot it in anyway. As you say the bars are very thin, I think you can make it bigger by increasing the fig size.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to solve your problem:
let sourcedf contain the input data in the form of two columns 'TimeStamp' & 'Load'
Then do the following:

```
sourcedf['Date'] = sourcedf.apply(lambda row: row['Date_Time'].date(), axis = 1)
dfg = sourcedf.groupby('Date')
ldList = list(dfg['Load'].max().to_list())
tgtDate = dfg.max().index.to_list()[dList.index(max(ldList))]
dfout = sourcedf[sourcedf['Date'] == tgtDate]
```

dfout will then contain just the date on which the max load was experienced

Comment: Thanks "Mr itprorh66" for your response . the code provides the 24 hours readings of the day in which the system load is at its peak throughout all years -i.e only 24 hours [rows] - but what I want is 24 hours readings per year. I mean that the intended dataframe contains 24 hours reading[rows] time 8 years (number of years taken into consideration-here 2013 up to 2020).